# How to select/read/copy values after specific character in a string

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in this area, so I hope I could get some workaround to this

How can I read or copy or select the values of number after specific character in a string?

Let say I have a string:

> "ans=(any number submitted)"

how can I select the (any number submitted) part only?

Lets say the value submitted is 999.. thus the string would be "ans=999" .. how can I copy 999 in this case? I wanted to use the value later for atoi()

thank you in advance. really appreciate some help here

Answer (score 3):

Given a string in the form `ans=999`, you would normally use `strchr()` to find the `=`.

So,

```
char *arg = strchr(string, '=');
if (arg != NULL)
{
    arg++; /* we want to look at what's _after_ the '=' */

    printf("arg points to %s\n", arg);
}
else
    /* oops: there was no '=' in the input string */ ;
```

should print

```
arg points to 999
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I've successfully converted the value using atoi() too.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [strchr](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strchr.3.asp) function returns the string starting at the first instance of the specified character

Comment: Ah.. I've read on this before but didnt quite understand.. Now I know where to emphasize on..thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) :

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string str.

You just have to find the character `=` and take everything there is after :

```
#include <string.h>  // For strchr

char* ans = "ans=999";          // Your string with your example
char* num = strchr( ans, '=' ); // Retrieve a pointer to the first occurence found of =

if ( num != NULL )              // Test if we found an occurence
{
    arg++;                      // We want to begin after the '='

    printf( "The number : %s", arg ); // For example print it to see the result
}
else
{
    // Error, there is no = in the string
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I've successfully converted the value using atoi() too.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is using the strchr as mentioned above.  This points to where that character is first located in the string.  But if you know you have "ans=#" as the format every time.  Why waste CPU time on strchr?  A quicker way would be to sscanf.  An example would be:

```
char *string = "ans=999";
int number, scanned;

scanned = sscanf(string,"ans=%d",&number);

if(scanned < 1)
printf("sscanf failure\n");
```

What this does is grabs the 999 in the string and puts it to number.  sscanf also returns how many numbers were successfully scanned, so you can use that later on for error checking and so forth.